# Monitoring with Zabbix: Reducing granularity?

Tags: monitoring, lamp, zabbix

I've setup Zabbix on a small VPS recently and got it to monitor three other VPS's. Already we've got about 9.8 incoming values per second and the load on the Zabbix server are already topping. It's got 256M of memory along with APC as opcode cache to speed up PHP.

Is it possible to reduce the granularity, ie lower the incoming values to offload our Zabbix server as we're not monitoring misson-critical stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got 2 ways of doing this:

edit the templates used to increase the "interval" of checks (there is a mass update ability but use it sparingly), this means checks are done less often and thus should spare some capacity

on each vps, disable the checks you know you dont need, less checks means less work to do

also try editing your zabbix server and agent config on the monitoring vps to lower the number of processes it starts, to something like 2 agents and 4 servers

```
StartAgents=2
```

for agent config

```
 StartTrappers=2
 StartPollers=4
```

for server config

i have to point out that you are running on what is effectively the minimum requirements for zabbix server so you will have to reduce the amount of data you are processing if you want to add more, because zabbix is reliant on innodb with mysql you are pushing resource limits to start with, doubling ram would be a safer and more reliable option

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony! Will try these changes out. I know that we're living on the edge with these resources, but as a startup we're flipping every coin to get the most back :)

Comment: would something like pingdom not be a better fit then?

Comment: We'll be using Pingdom too, but only to ensure uptime from a third-party. ZABBIX is great to monitor certain applications/services and their impact on load

Comment: Reduce the frequency at which items are being gathered, the defaults are quite resource-hungry. Use mostly active items instead of passive, it's better for the load distribution as well.
Alternatively, with that few servers, you might want to look at hosted monitoring. http://tribily.com is hosted zabbix, which might be saving you a lot of hassle. Disclaimer: I'm the founder of tribily ;)

Comment: Reducing the number of trappers and pollers can cause you queue to back up and can lead to gaps in graphs.  You can most often leave the trappers/pollers as they are by default as their resource footprint is very small.